# MySQL - Can I create an index only to one particular partition

Tags: mysql, partitioning

Since partition also splits the table into subtables, I wanted to know if there is any way to index the partitioned table one by one based on the partition name or id. I am asking this because, my table can have 1 Billion+ rows and add index query takes long hours/day, so wanted to check if I can start adding index based on the partition that I think is more important first or vice versa.

Comment: The index is a sub-entity of a table. When you index partitioned table, the whole table is indexed, but each partition is indexed independently (see [Partitioning Keys, Primary Keys, and Unique Keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html) for some details and consequences).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, MySQL has no syntax to support creating indexes on a partitioned table one partition at a time. The index will be added to all partitions in one `ALTER TABLE` or `CREATE INDEX` statement.

At my company, we execute schema changes using [pt-online-schema-change](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-online-schema-change.html), a script that allows clients to continue reading and writing the table while the alter is running. It might even take longer to run the schema change, but since it doesn't block clients, this doesn't cause a problem.

The script is part of the Percona Toolkit, which is a free, open-source collection of tools written in Perl and Bash.